# LINUX: List contents of a outside folder or of a subfolder without leaving current folder

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ls

I have a c program that watches over a folder somewhere in your directory (location is given when program starts up). One of its tasks is to tell the user what contents are stored in that specified folder. I was thinking of piping the ls command but I'm unsure how to get contents of a folder in which you are not currently in. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: unless you have a specific programming question, this post might better belong on http://www.superuser.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use ls?

```
ls /path/to/directory
```

Alternatively, use `opendir()` and `readdir()`, see `man 3 opendir` and `man 3 readdir`

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. I knew the question was a little dumb but I couldnt find an example of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

maybe you are looking for

```
ls /path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the contents of the parent directory you can use `ls ..`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are suitable if you are at the terminal, but you would probably like a C API, rather than an expensive call to fork the process and list a directory.

For a C API, you'll want to take a look at `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` - [this is a perfectly good reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/opendir.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls` just as you suggested.  Check out the [`ls` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls).  Example:

```
$ ls /tmp/somedir
file1  file2
```